# How to slide "new procducts" block to right side top corner in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

i am having problem in the layout of Prestashop theme as i am not able to slide the "new product"  block to the right hand side upper corner.Please will nay one tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would try transplanting the module to the new block, unless your just moving the module position to the top of the list. Try moving it up under Modules --> Positions in the BO if your just trying to move it up to the top right corner of the center column.

Comment: Can you post a link to your shop? You tried moving it to the top position? I'm not sure what you are referring to, the top right of what? The header? The right column? The main column?

Comment: yes i am trying to move it top-right corner below the menu bar and at the corner of the page i mean int the right column

Comment: You moved the module to the top position of the right column in Module --> Positions? And you also played around with the CSS to try to move it around using floats or something similar?

Comment: I want to shift my "our stories" and "contact us" module from left to right column. Will please any one tell me how to do it?

Comment: Simply remove the modules from the displayLeftColumn and transplant them to displayRightColumn under Modules --> Positions under the BO like I was saying.